# Are there any journals that pay reviewers?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review

Being a young researcher myself I received a comment from my colleague that some of the journals are paying reviewers for the reviewing process.

When I gave it a thought, it started to make more sense.
In case of high quality, respected journal, an institution may consider itself privileged to have a reviewer of such journal and allow the reviewer to dedicate small proportion of his/her daily activities just on the reviewing process.

The reviewer being paid, has more obligations to provide thorough in depth review.

Does that hold true for some journals or is it just a myth?

Comment: Besides _traditional_ journal paying reviewers, there are also few _open access_ journals, which pay reviewers if they are able to provide a review within X days. These journals offer an optional, paid "fast-track" peer review to authors. Please note that I am referring to proper open access journals here, not those considered predatory. I am almost sure there were an experience report on this website, but I cannot find the answer yet.

Comment: @dgraziotin - may I ask what do you mean by _traditional_ journal? Payment for fast-track review seems interesting - I didn't know about that. I can see, however, this being a trend going the wrong way.

Comment: The open access community likes to call _traditional_ journals the subscription-based journals, or those that are hidden behind a paywall.

Comment: Once you accept a review you are obligated to provide a thorough in depth review whether or not you are being paid.

Comment: @StrongBad: Agreed. In depth is however quite relative term. Because we, human beings, like to interpret the law the way we want, some may provide _more_ some _less_ in depth reviews. Some may feel motivated and driven by the price to provide highly desired suggestions and recommendations that are not mandatory for every field.

Comment: One alternative I've heard is to pay not in money, but in a discount or waiver for publication or subscription fees.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's not a myth. There are/have been some journals that pay peer reviewers. For example:

- The [New England Journal of Medicine](http://a-c-elitzur.co.il/uploads/articlesdocs/PeerReview1.pdf) used to pay $5 per review, until some reviewers complained that "if that was the price that this eminent journal placed on their opinion, the New England Journal of Medicine should seek referees elsewhere"
- The [Lancet](http://journalology.blogspot.com/2007/01/why-reviewers-decline-and-paying-for.html) reportedly pays for peer review "sometimes"
- Reviewers for journals published by the [American Economic Association](http://www.aeaweb.org/aea_journals.php) earn [$100](http://www.aeaweb.org/aer/reviewers.php) for each "timely" review.
- [Zentralblatt MATH](http://zbmath.org/reviewer-service/en/benefits/) (zbMATH) pays 2.56 EUR per review, although this is for post-publication reviews that are then published.
- The [Journal of Medical Internet Research](http://www.jmir.org/cms/view/Instructions_for_Authors%3aInstructions_for_Authors_of_JMIR#Fast-track) offers "a review model in which selected peer reviewers may be paid to deliver high-quality and speedy peer-review reports" (if authors pay an extra fee for the fast-track option)
- The [Arabian Journal for Science and Engineering](http://web.firat.edu.tr/dhanbay/h3.htm) has offered an honorarium of $100 for each "timely" review
- [Drugs in Context](http://drugsincontext.com/authors) pays its peer reviewers an honorarium of unspecified amount, supposedly "to motivate rigorous peer review"
- The [International Institute for Science, Technology and Education](http://www.iiste.org/career.html) (which is on [Beall's list](http://scholarlyoa.com/2012/12/06/bealls-list-of-predatory-publishers-2013/) of allegedly predatory open-access journals and publishers) pays reviewers for its journals $60-$100 per review

Whether *the reviewer being paid, has more obligations to provide thorough in depth review* is true or not is entirely uncertain, though.

Comment: that is quite nice list of records busting my myth. May I ask if you know of more of those journals that are related to life sciences/medicine? Also, do you know how does the paid reviewing process relate to a full time job that such a reviewer would have?

Comment: Cool, +1. I am especially intrigued by the odd 2.56 EUR from zbMATH, which just happens to be exactly 5 DM at the conversion rate used during the switchover in 1999-2002... So they apparently haven't changed this in at least 12 years. Fascinating.

Comment: In most cases it's either a trivial honorarium, or a slightly higher amount related to that "fast-track" option offered by some open-access journals. A company called [Rubriq](http://exchanges.wiley.com/blog/2013/09/17/a-new-approach-to-peer-review-an-interview-with-keith-collier-co-founder-of-rubriq/) is trying to make a "paid external peer review" business model work, we'll see how that works out...

Comment: @ff524: zbMath is slightly different. The "review" they refer to are not pre-publication peer reviews, but post-publication summary and discussions. In particular, the reviews are not anonymous and are published. There's an analogous service in the United States by the [American Mathematical Society](http://www.ams.org/publications/math-reviews/math-reviews) (who gives you essentially a gift card that you can spend buying AMS publications for each review; IIRC the rate is something like 4USD per review.)

Comment: @WillieWong - I guess you are referring to a post-publication reviewing process similar to what I'm more familiar with as f1000. You are right by pointing it out that this is not a pre-publication review. However it is a reviewing process too and it is paid. For that reason I think it could be included in this list. I think this question could be fairly generic.

Comment: @WillieWong: no hard feelings :) Just a part of discussion. Also that let me clarify that the question could be fairly open, about the entire reviewing process, being either pre- or post-publishing.

Comment: @mjp: there is a tiny difference with the Faculty of 1000 (this is not to say that the comparison is not apt; I am just being pedantic). To the best of my knowledge the F1000 process involve a selection of only the "good" articles for recommendation. Whereas with zbMath and AMS-MR every article in the indexed journals are reviewed; sometimes [this leads to hilarity](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/mr.html).

Comment: @ff524: Would you be interested in making this answer a community wiki, so people can contribute and create a larger resource?

Comment: Has the ZBL policy changed recently? I've reviewed a couple of papers for them in the past few years and never got any money. Maybe it's because I'm in the US and they can't send me euros?

Comment: @Nate from the linked policy, it seems you have to explicitly let them know you want your token 2.56 EUR. Try it and let us know what happens :)

Comment: @mjp  the question is "are there journals..." not "what are all the journals..." (the latter would almost certainly be closed on Academia. SE) so I don't really see the need. In any case, anyone can suggest edits.

Comment: @ff524: Aha, they do it by bank transfer, and it costs much more than EUR 2.56 to wire money overseas. But I didn't know about the Springer book discount either, that could be useful.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Is this post useful the the extend that people start making money by reading it or what ? :)

Answer (score 7):

This is not quite what you asked, but book publishers often pay reviewers to evaluate a manuscript and give their opinion on whether to publish it. I recently received $125 US for just such a review. It was less work than reviewing a typical journal article (since I wasn't asked to check technical details) but had a short deadline of just a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 2):

With the advent of a huge number of online journals, requests for reviewing papers is increasing. Most eminent scientists are too busy with other more important things than reviewing someone else's papers. The end result of all this is that journals seek opinions of people who may not be really competent to provide a fair and accurate review. The other problem is that reviewing manuscripts is not considered an added merit/honor/qualification. Thus reviewing a paper for a journal has absolutely no advantage for the reviewer. The simplest solution would be that journals start paying at least a 100 dollars and up to a reviewer. I am declining to review several papers every month but if I would get extra 500 dollars for reviewing 5 papers a month, it will be an added incentive to review a MS. In other words, journals should really consider the option of paying the reviewers. They are already being paid a hefty some as publication charges and open access publishing. They can share a small part of that profit with the reviewers.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. This site follows a strict question-and-answer format and answers should address the question, which in this case is about what is done and not what should be done. I am therefore flagging your answer for deletion.