# How can one find journals paying authors or reviewers?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, online-publication

How can one find journals paying authors or reviewers? 
I've read about some old examples (probably about a relatively small university I can't recall) but I'm wondering if is there a directory or shared keyword or do they just go by word of mouth?
Can I write on topics I don't have a PhD about but I'm otherwise competent on?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think that such journals are still around. Nobody would pay for them.

Comment: It's usually other way around. In some journals, you pay when you want your paper published.

Comment: Publish in Russian. Quite a number of Russian mathematical journals that are eventually translated into English pay their authors.

Comment: On payment for review: a few economics journals http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68191/why-dont-researchers-request-payment-for-refereeing/68199#68199 and a small number of others here and there http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/20932/27825

Answer (score 4):

Write for almost anything else than scientific journals and you can get paid. 
Also, if you are not doing research / don't have a PhD in a topic, something else than scientific publishing is much more easier.

Comment: Good answer, except: the OP didn't mention science.

Comment: 1 My answer is not exclusive to science. 2 it is Academia here, we talk about science. If someone wants to be a writer, he/she should understand contexts.

Comment: "2 it is Academia here, we talk about science." That is exactly my point -- academia is not synonymous with science, nor is academia.SE.  I took your use of "science" to be a synecdoche for "academia".  If you really mean science, then your first statement is false, because of the enormous number of non-scientific academic journals for which authors are still not paid.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It helped to clarify the issue and gave tremendous good advice